# How to Calculate in vTiger

Tags: vtiger

I created a numeric commission field and a numeric total field (value of the product / commission)
How can I do this calculation in the vTiger Builder Module?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use vitger workflow update field task

Comment: Ok, but there is no automatic update, only when it is saved that the calculations are solved.
I need an automatic update.